# How to access php variable in javascript using echo statement

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to redirect to same page i am on but with some variable.
The code i have written here is simple to understand. In my project there are too many html lines lying between them.

```
<?php 
    $id = 11;
 ?>
 <?php 
    echo '<script> window.location.href = "index.php?id=$id"</script>';
  ?>
```

It should take me to same page with like **"index.php?id=11"** but it loads page as **"index.php?id="**. What i can do to over come this ?

Comment: switch places of ' and "

Comment: see [global variables(https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php $id = 11; ?>
<?php 
    echo '<script> window.location.href = "index.php?id='.$id.'"</script>';
?>
```

Comment: @faizan Did this help you?

Answer (score 1):

single quoted strings do not expand vars (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), check the Note.

Your example works this way:

```php
<?php
    $id = 11;
 ?>
 <?php
    echo '<script> window.location.href = "index.php?id=' . $id . '"</script>';
?>
```